# SDDM (seems) Broken

Tags: kubuntu, sddm

on Kubuntu 2204, all recent patches in-place.
KDE Plasma version: 5.24.6
KDE Framework: 5.92.0
Qt version: 5.13.3
Kernel version: 5.15.0-47-generic (64bit)
Graphics platform: x11
Relative Humidity: 63%
Current temp: 69°F
Lunar Phase: 25.8% Waning Crescent

So I attempted to "Change Background" on the only two displayed "Breeze" items (duplicate?) shown on Login Screen (SDDM) Settings page.
Initially, I selected a .bmp, hit Apply button, rebooted, and am presented with a huge keyboard, as though the OS now thinks this OptiPlex 790 PC has turned itself into a Cellular Telephone with a touchscreen.

I hit the [KB symbol] button, see a blue patterned (Plasma x11) background with white boxes for each user account, select my user account, am able to log in, with everything looking as it has once logged in.

So i select a .jpg picture, reboot, no change, still blue patterned (Plasma x11) log on screen.

so I press the [Apply Plasma Settings] button, the RESET to Default Settings, reboot, no change.

so I attempt to change to anything else by hitting [Get New SDDM Theme..] button, and Kubuntu complains about [CONNECTION REFUSED!] and while there seem to be listings, none are showing any picture previews.

so I go directly to kde.org and even there, none of the picture previews are showing for SDDM Themes. (showing broken pic icon)

All I wanted to do was change. a. picture.
yet the above occurred.
what caused the problem?
what can be done to:

1. resolve where-in one CAN select a local picture for back ground.
2. relatedly, not have either local account display on the logon screen, just username/password fields.

Comment: on further research, it seems pling.com was being blocked by NextDNS for something untoward on pling's part. allowing that domain brings pictures; however, am receiving a very cryptic error, and there seems no option to add screenshot here. so, just think SDDM, add new theme, cryptic error to know what my system is displaying.

Comment: If you have more info for the question use EDIT to add that info to the question. Please make it clear what you are adding.

Answer (score -1):

This should fix it for you

Open the terminal

`sudo apt-get purge sddm-...`

Then

`sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`

Ensure that you run both scripts before reboot

Good luck